# Getting the select option value to pass into action attribute so it can pass as url and open up the website

Tags: javascript, html, select, action

The Url website is appearing in the address, but it's not opening the website page....

```
<form action=" ">
 <select name="url">
 <option value="https://www.google.com">google</option>
 <option value="https://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
 function SetData(){
 var select = document.getElementById('url').value;
 var test_id = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
 document.form.action = test_id;
 form.submit();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `document.form.action` is not referring to what you think it is. Actually it would cause an error, if your function ever was executed. Just give an `id` to your form, and get a reference with `document.getElementById`. Also, you need to attach `submit` listener to the form to execute your function.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this...it's just a clickhandler on the submit button which opens the selected webpage.

HTML:

```
<select id="url">
   <option value="https://www.google.com">Google</option>
   <option value="https://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
 </select>
<button type="button" onclick="openUrl()">Open</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function openUrl(){
   var select = document.getElementById("url");
   var url = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
   window.open(url,'_blank');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kamys76g/

Comment: But how does it go through the action attribute?  The purpose is to have a form where I can select a website and pass values.  My project involves testing websites by having a select tag to pick a website then add username and password to access the page. The goal is to put a list together of test websites into one html and not multiple htmls.

Comment: In addition, this will include a post method so PHP is also involved.  My only concern is getting a option value to go through the action attribute.

Comment: If you want to set the value to the action-attribute (but you should read Teemus comment on top), see:

https://jsfiddle.net/kamys76g/1/

Comment: Thank you mxlse and Teemus!! The url went through the action attribute by making the input type as submit.  The input text values also went through and I was able to get access within the webpage. Making this into a form will save me a lot of time and hassle. Thanks again -Sal

Answer (score 0):

here i have changed some script 
when click on button page is redirect as on selected value and also attribute is posted in querystring

```
 <script>
     function SetData(){
     var select = document.getElementsByName('url')[0].value;
     document.forms[0].action = select;
     document.forms[0].submit();
     }
    </script>

<form action=" ">
 <select name="url">
 <option value="https://www.google.com">google</option>
 <option value="https://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="SetData()"/>
</form>
```